# Connect Multiple Computers Java UDP

Tags: java, udp, datagram

im trying to connect multiple clients from different computers and send messages to each other using UDP, but this works only locally! can anyone point me out why its not working on other computers?

PS : i tried running the client on other computers and gave my ip address as the host, it still don't work.

this is my **Client.java**

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*; 

public class Client {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {  

        // The default port     
        int clientport = 4000;
        String host = "localhost";

        if (args.length < 1) {
           System.out.println("Usage: UDPClient " + "Now using host = " + host + ", Port# = " + clientport);
        } 
        // Get the port number to use from the command line
        else {      
           //host = args[0];
           clientport = Integer.valueOf(args[0]).intValue();
           System.out.println("Usage: UDPClient " + "Now using host = " + host + ", Port# = " + clientport);
        } 

        // Get the IP address of the local machine - we will use this as the address to send the data to
        InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName(host);

        SenderThread sender = new SenderThread(ia, clientport);
        sender.start();
        ReceiverThread receiver = new ReceiverThread(sender.getSocket());
        receiver.start();
    }
} 

    class SenderThread extends Thread {

    private InetAddress serverIPAddress;
    private DatagramSocket udpClientSocket;
    private boolean stopped = false;
    private int serverport;

    public SenderThread(InetAddress address, int serverport) throws SocketException {
        this.serverIPAddress = address;
        this.serverport = serverport;
        // Create client DatagramSocket
        this.udpClientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        this.udpClientSocket.connect(serverIPAddress, serverport);
    }
    public void halt() {
        this.stopped = true;
    }
    public DatagramSocket getSocket() {
        return this.udpClientSocket;
    }

    public void run() {       
        try {    
            //send blank message
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            data = "".getBytes();
            DatagramPacket blankPacket = new DatagramPacket(data,data.length , serverIPAddress, serverport);
            udpClientSocket.send(blankPacket);

            // Create input stream
            BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            while (true) 
            {
                if (stopped)
                    return;

                // Message to send
                String clientMessage = inFromUser.readLine();

                if (clientMessage.equals("."))
                    break;

                // Create byte buffer to hold the message to send
                byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];

                // Put this message into our empty buffer/array of bytes
                sendData = clientMessage.getBytes();

                // Create a DatagramPacket with the data, IP address and port number
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, serverIPAddress, serverport);

                // Send the UDP packet to server
                System.out.println("I just sent: "+clientMessage);
                udpClientSocket.send(sendPacket);

                Thread.yield();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
}   

class ReceiverThread extends Thread {

    private DatagramSocket udpClientSocket;
    private boolean stopped = false;

    public ReceiverThread(DatagramSocket ds) throws SocketException {
        this.udpClientSocket = ds;
    }

    public void halt() {
        this.stopped = true;
    }

    public void run() {

        // Create a byte buffer/array for the receive Datagram packet
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

        while (true) {            
            if (stopped)
            return;

            // Set up a DatagramPacket to receive the data into
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            System.out.println("I am in the reader!");
            try {
                // Receive a packet from the server (blocks until the packets are received)
                udpClientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                System.out.println("Am i receiving?");
                // Extract the reply from the DatagramPacket      
                String serverReply =  new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());

                // print to the screen
                System.out.println("UDPClient: Response from Server: \"" + serverReply + "\"\n");

                Thread.yield();
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is my **Server.java**

```
import java.net.*; // Imported because the Socket class is needed
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Server {   

    private static HashSet<Integer> portSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

       // The default port     
        int serverport = 4000;        

        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: UDPServer " + "Now using Port# = " + serverport);
        } 
        // Get the port number & host to use from the command line
        else {            
            serverport = Integer.valueOf(args[0]).intValue();
            System.out.println("Usage: UDPServer " + "Now using Port# = " + serverport);
        }

        // Open a new datagram socket on the specified port
        DatagramSocket udpServerSocket = new DatagramSocket(serverport);        

        System.out.println("Server started...\n");

        while(true)
        {
            // Create byte buffers to hold the messages to send and receive
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];          

            // Create an empty DatagramPacket packet
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

            // Block until there is a packet to receive, then receive it  (into our empty packet)
            udpServerSocket.receive(receivePacket);           

            // Extract the message from the packet and make it into a string, then trim off any end characters
            String clientMessage = (new String(receivePacket.getData())).trim();

            // Print some status messages
            System.out.println("Client Connected - Socket Address: " + receivePacket.getSocketAddress());
            System.out.println("Client message: \"" + clientMessage + "\"");          

            // Get the IP address and the the port number which the received connection came from
            InetAddress clientIP = receivePacket.getAddress();           

            // Print out status message
            System.out.println("Client IP Address & Hostname: " + clientIP + ", " + clientIP.getHostName() + "\n");

            // Get the port number which the recieved connection came from
            int clientport = receivePacket.getPort();
            System.out.println("Adding "+clientport);
            portSet.add(clientport);

            // Response message         
            String returnMessage = clientMessage.toUpperCase();          
            System.out.println(returnMessage);
            // Create an empty buffer/array of bytes to send back 
            byte[] sendData  = new byte[1024];

            // Assign the message to the send buffer
            sendData = returnMessage.getBytes();

            for(Integer port : portSet) 
            {
                System.out.println(port != clientport);
                if(port != clientport) 
                {
                    // Create a DatagramPacket to send, using the buffer, the clients IP address, and the clients port
                    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, clientIP, port); 
                    System.out.println("Sending");
                    // Send the echoed message          
                    udpServerSocket.send(sendPacket);    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to uncomment this `//host = args[0];`?

Comment: You can try http://jgroups.org/

Comment: @musib apparently i cannot use anything only this ! thanx man

Comment: @NicolasFilotto yeah i did, but still not working :(

Comment: You want to do unicast or multicast ? I mean if node 1 sends a message, you want him to send it to everybody or just one given node?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto i want to send it to everybody, like a group chat! so far locally if i run client many times i can pass the same message! i want to connect to the client from another computer! but it doesnt work!
i want to multicast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you are connecting your UDP sockets to 'localhost'.

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: Err, not connect to 'localhost'?

Comment: so if i want other computers to connect to my computer , no to use localhost? then what? please exaplain

Answer (score 1):

In your client code, you are connecting to the localhost which means 127.0.0.1 which is bound to your system only.
If you are trying from another system, you should use the IP of the machine which is running the server(use the command `ipconfig` if you are on windows) or you can broadcast on your gateway IP.
Search Google for broadcasting UDP in Java.